# How can I decode a value in Javascript which is encoded with HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, decoding

I have a HTML element with a `data-` attribute, which is encoded on the server with  `HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode`

So for example:

```
data-id="This is &amp;quot;an example&amp;quot; attribute">
```

Now I want to read the value in JavaScript and therefor I want to decode it. However, I can't seem to find any decoding functions in JavaScript (except decodeUri, but that doesn't work)

If there is an alternative to `HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode`, that's also ok.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a duplicate, because I think attribute encoding is not the same as HTML encoding?

Comment: it is a subset of HTML encoding (specifically only handling the `<`, `"`, `&` characters)

Comment: Ok, in that case, thanks